# Scala: type-safe way to implicitly convert between abstract types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Lets say I have two abstract, unrelated types `A` and `B` (sealed traits with no implementation details if it makes any difference). I would like to be able to return `A`s in places that are expecting `B`s, and vice-versa.

this:

```
implicit def aToB(a: A): B = a.asInstanceOf[B]
implicit def bToA(b: B): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
implicit def convertSeq[T, U](s: Seq[T]): Seq[U] = s.map(_.asInstanceOf[U])
```

will work because I know that all types that extend `A` also extend `B`, but the compiler doesn't know this.  Is there a type-safe way to do this?

Edit to add more concrete detail:

```
trait A

trait B

class X extends A with B
class Y extends A with B
class Z extends A with B

def doSomething(): Seq[A] = Seq(new X(), new Y(), new Z())

def publicFacingMethod1(): Seq[A] = doSomething()

// how can I do this?
def publicFacingMethod2(): Seq[B] = doSomething()
```

Comment: if all subtypes of `A` are also subtypes of `B`, it sounds like you simply don't need two separate traits. Or, at least, need the third one: `trait C extends A with B`.

Comment: conceptually, yes.  100% correct.  Unfortunately I don't control the library the are defined in.  I would rather not force a third boilerplate type into the clients of the library.  However if I could also convert _that_ implicitly...

Comment: Actually that's just an extension of my issue.  I already have `X`s, `Y`s, and `Z`s which `extends A with B`. I have separate methods that expect to handle either `Seq[A]` or `Seq[B]`.  I have a method that generates only `Seq[A]`, and I want to reuse that logic for the method that handles `Seq[B]` without changing the existing interface.

Comment: In the example I provided above, it will work if I change the type of `doSomething` to `Seq[A with B]`.  Not Ideal, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
implicit def convertSeq[T <: A, U >: B](s: Seq[T])(implicit ev: A => B): Seq[U] = s.map(ev)
```

instead of your definition of `convertSeq`.